# How can I measure the similarity between 2 IP addresses? Is there any code to re-use?

Tags: preprocessing, similarity, distance

I need to measure the similarity of 2 IP addresses. I could not find any sample code in scala or other languages to find the distance between 2 IPs.

Comment: How do you want to define distance, geographically? If so, use a GeoIP service. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Emre Can `word2vec` also be used for this purpose? Maybe, :) I hadn't thought of before.

Comment: You could learn an embedding but it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Emre Actually, it was a trivial opinion but maybe it can learn to find the region. I guess the distance between IPs can be learned.

Comment: You could learn embeddings for IP Addresses. Ring et al. did that already for IP Addresses in their [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8215725
).

Answer (score 1):

In Python there is [the ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html) which can convert an IP address to an integer, then simply subtract to find the difference.

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
int(ip_address(‘10.0.0.1’))
```

Comment: What does this difference represent? It seems meaningless to me.

Comment: @emre best I could come up with given the vague problem description. Just trying to help a new member!